# how to remove and add classes using same function?

Tags: jquery, html, css

in the following `url` here is my code m trying to hide and show the portion using the jquery and also for in the css there are image up and down its working perfectly for show and hide the but it didn't change the image from up to down and again from down to up?

how can i do this using jquery?
http://jsfiddle.net/mohsinali89/mspFH/

Comment: Commas and periods. Use them.

Comment: Punctuation: it's there to help you. Use it and make your question more understandable, increasing the chance you will get a useful answer.

Comment: have you tried http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#hideShow").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('hide show');
        //some other stuff here
    });
});
```